# Comparison between normal array vs generated by back-tick array

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, ecmascript-6, backticks

I am creating an array by two way.

- my first way is creating an array normally
- my second way is creating an array by using backticks function

```js
let array=["1234"];

function createArrayByBakticks(obj)
{
return obj;
}

let backtickArray = createArrayByBakticks `1234`;// it's responding an array

console.log(array); //1st way and it returns an array 
console.log(backtickArray ); //2nd way and it returns a same array 

backtickArray.push(1);// but it's throwing an error while push a new value. 

// Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot add property 1, object is not extensible


console.log(backtickArray);
```

Above both ways are return as a array data.  *But the second array is not supporting inbuilt function of array which is generated by back-ticks.* ***WHY? And what is the difference between in the both ways***?

Comment: what is `var let` ?

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut oops. type issue and edited now

Comment: @RameshRajendran You still have an error in your code

Comment: @Weedoze I have updated my snippet. Thanks mates :)

Comment: You still misspelled your `backticksArray` ...

Comment: OOOFFFF ... I am blind .... **Updated**

Comment: **Again**, you misspelled it.

Comment: @Zenoo What man??

Comment: In which sense `\`1234\`` is an array? It's just a string, not an array.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti **createArrayByBakticks `1234`**  it will create an array

Answer (score 2):

`createArrayByBakticks` is used as a so-called tag function. The first argument passed to the function is an array containing all strings of the template literal.

If you dive deep into the language specification, [section 12.2.9.3](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-gettemplateobject), then you will see the following step is performed after the array has been created:

> 14. Perform SetIntegrityLevel(template, "frozen").

This means that in your case `obj`is frozen and no property can be added. That's why invoking `push` doesn't work.

You can confirm this by calling `console.log(Object.isFrozen(backtickArray))`.

Comment: Thanks, great answer

Answer (score 1):

The array returns from the function *by value*, meaning it's immutable.

If you use `concat`, you'll get a new copy of it, which you can modify:

```js
let array = ["1234"];

function createArrayByBakticks(obj) {
  return obj;
}

let backtickArray = createArrayByBakticks `1234`; // it's responding an array

console.log(array); //1st way and it returns an array 
console.log(backtickArray); //2nd way and it returns a same array 

let newArray = backtickArray.concat(1); // a new mutable array is generated
newArray.push(2);                       // so you can even keep modifying it
console.log(newArray);
```